# Are there other non-trivial wave functions then sine?

Tags: functions

I only know the following wave functions:

- sine
- waves which are based on sine (like cosine, or $sin(x^2)$)
- trivial waves repeating a geometric shape (saw wave, square wave, ...)

Are there other wave functions than these?

Comment: What do you mean by "wave function", exactly?

Comment: A function going up and down endless times. But not trivial like repeating a part of another function.

Comment: Any periodic function satisfies this. That includes functions like $\tan,\sec,\csc,\cot$.

Comment: Yes but these can all be expressed with sine. Are there periodic functions which cannot be expressed with sine?

Comment: All reasonably nice periodic functions can be expanded in Fourier series, which more or less means that they “can be expressed with sine”.

Comment: @HansLundmark Fourier series are only an approximation. I am asking for a periodic function which is not the sum of sinusoids. Or in other word: A periodic function which cannot be exactly expressed with a fourier series.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a function based on the fractional-part and the absolute value of a real number such as

$$
f(x)=|2\cdot\{|x|\}-1|
$$

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Lundmark has pointed out, this is a fundamentally ill-defined question, but it seems you're hunting for an example. Pavel R.'s works, but I have a feeling you might classify it as a "trivial waves repeating a geometric shape."

If you want one that looks more like a proper wave, we can just construct one in the same way we define sine in middle school, only replace the unit circle with something else:

Consider a closed loop in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with the property that every ray emanating from the origin crosses the loop at a unique point. Then, define $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by letting $f(\theta)$ be the y-value of the intersection point of the ray at an angle $\theta$ radians from the x-axis.

Then, we can see that this function is periodic (with period $2\pi$). You can convince yourself that $f$ must go "up and down endless times," but in general is not "trivial like repeating a part of another function." Whether or not you consider this a "wave" is subjective, but if you let the loop be some vaguely round shape, then the resulting function will be vaguely wave-like, while not being directly related to $sin(x)$.

Comment: Can you name an example resulting function?

Comment: Well, sine, square, and sawtooth waves can all be represented (to some degree) using this construction with some loop in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but that's not the point. These are all particular cases of a general construction which creates "waves." You can imagine perturbing the loop to create a slightly different wave. With this view, it's clear that there do exist "non-trivial waves" that aren't explicitly expressed in terms of sine.